Baking procedural material from procedural model
I'm pretty new to Blender and so have only used it occasionally for small tasks that are not possible in 3DS Max. What however blew me away completely yesterday is the procedural stuff!
So I went ahead and turned an imported FBX model into rocks following this tutorial (pure magic tbh!):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QA13LPCZ3dM
The result looks like this:

As you can see both the model and the material (because of the blending overlap required for the rocks) are now procedural. However I do need to export what I'm seeing here with UV Maps and a standard baked texture.
I tried a few tutorials for that (e.g. this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2kFeMBBBjc) but the problem is that once I'm switching for the UV Editing tab for baking, this one only "sees" the base model, before the rocks have been generated:

Any help in pointing me into the right direction would be much appreciated!

If you are asking how to do baking, I would recommend watching some tutorials. That will be way more practical than anything anybody could write in a single answer. If you need help with the specific case, people will need to know everything about it so it would be best to share your .blend file. You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ to share .blend files on BSE. You are using normal map incorrectly, by the way - you need a Normal Map node. Else than that the screenshots don't help a lot since they are not showing anything meaningful at all.

Not sure if that's what you are looking for or if there are reasons this might not be enough, but you can apply the Geometry Nodes modifier to get the resulting geometry. You probably need to realize instances(there is a node for that) inside the geometry nodes and make sure it's all mesh data in the result before doing so.

My apologies, it looks like I missed your reply earlier. I agree that watching more tutorials would be helpful but at this stage I'm not even sure where you begin. Therefore it would be much appreciated if you could have a look at my file I uploaded here: 
